# Sending an Email via Ria Services

Tags: silverlight, ria

I'm currently writting a Silverlight application using Ria Services.  I want to add the feature of allowing to reset their password if they have forgotten it.

Is it possible to send Emails via Ria services??

If i create a Ria Service that inherits from DomainService, and create a method in the new service that sends emails, will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just mark your method with `[Invoke]` and it should be availabe to be called on the client.